# How can I separate a column on a web page depending on whether or not the browser is mobile?

Tags: html, css, browser, mobile

I have a site that is mostly designed for viewing on Android and iPhone devices. However, it is, of course, possible that people can view it on the web from a desktop or laptop.

The site is currently built to be a skinny width, 320 pixels wide, to accomodate most handheld devices. And actually, I like the layout so I don't mind that people on desktops see the same interface as handhelds. I like the consistency of the interface across devices.

What I'd ideally like to do is have additional information display for people viewing the site on larger monitors. Like so:

[image]

The key point that I'm stuck on is how to prevent Interface B from being downloaded or offered to the mobile devices. I know how to create an extra DIV and hide it using CSS based on browser identification. However, for a variety of reasons, it is important that Interface B not simply be hidden from some devices, but the data not even be transferred.

Is this possible?

An ideal solution should include the following considerations:

- The default is to assume a device is mobile and only offer Interface
  A. Only if the "browser sniffing" comes back with a high certainty
  (well, as certain as it can get) that the device is a certain white
  list of known desktop browsers, then show interface B.
- A solution that works on the server side. Again, no data from
  Interface B should be transferred if the visitor is suspected to be
  on a mobile.
- Interface A and B can be separated by frames, DIVs, iFrames... I'm
  agnostic about that, but I'm more familiar with CSS, so having them
  in two different DIVs might be easier for me to grasp.

Comment: What server side language are you using? If static files, you could make the detection in Javascript, and redirect to separate HTML files with or without the B interface using `location.href`.

Comment: Currently the site is static HTML with a heavy Javascript component, and they comminicate by JSON with a PHP/MySQL backend. I'd ideally like to solve this on the server side, but your Javascript solution is noted.

Comment: Use PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to detect the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use browser sniffing at all, but CSS 3 Media Queries to find out if "Interface B" fits and load it's content with AJAX only if it's displayed.

Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
     #interface-b {
       display: none;
     }
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   // Using jQuery for convience here
   // Let #interface-b be empty originally, 
   // and load it's content with AJAX only if needed.
   jQuery(function() {
      if (jQuery("#interface-b").is(":visible")) {
        jQuery("#interface-b").load(...);
      }
   });
</script>
```

(EDIT: Added `only` keyword for better backwards compatibility)

Comment: Interesting. What will happen with browsers not capable of CSS3, though? What does it fall back to?

Comment: Browsers that don't understand the media query should ignore the `display: none` so it will be displayed normally. There are several syntax features such as the `only` keyword that help incompatible browsers ignore it.

Comment: This is a very cool solution. However, unless I'm mistaken, this is set up to default to displaying the B interface unless explicitly told not to. I think in my situation it would be better to have the reverse. To only show A, and not show B, by default, and only show B if conditions are met. Or am I not understanding what is being done here?

Comment: @Dave Well, yes and no. The DIV (or any other HTML element), which should contain "Interface B" and which I gave the ID `interface-b`, will be shown by default. However my idea is that that DIV should be empty by default, and not until the JavaScript has determined that the DIV is being displayed, then the content (the actual "Interface B") shall be loaded (using jQuery [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) ).

Answer (score 1):

1) Check http://us.php.net/get_browser --> use 'ismobiledevice' field of 'get_browser'
You may need an up to date php_browscap.ini, but you can get it [here](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads)
Just make a simple if-statement for then to evaluate if you want to 'print the div'. (Tell me, if you don't understand exactly what I mean)

2) Have a "fallback" JS, hiding the second div (should be empty anyway)